# Is there an invertible matrix that transposes?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Quick question:

I was asked if there exists an invertible matrix $P$ over the complex numbers such that for **any** matrix $A$:

$PAP^{-1} = A^{T}$

I don't know how to prove it, but I don't think this is true. I know every matrix is similair to its transpose, but it can't be the same matrix $P$ for **all** matrices...So my gut feeling tells me no, but how do I show it?

Comment: Don't you mean to ask if for any matrix $A$ there exists $P$ with the given property?

Comment: No. I mean exactly the opposite. That there is a matrix $P$ that transposes ALL matrices.

Comment: In fact there is, and the answer is here: http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS/Repository/1.0/Disseminate?view=body&id=pdf_1&handle=euclid.pjm/1103039127

Comment: @DonAntonio That paper is about the statement in my comment.

Comment: Yes it seems that it is...Let me stress the question again. I am not asking if for any matrix A there is a matrix P such that this property is true. I'm asking if is there a matrix P (one matrix) that has this property with all other matrices. a matrix P such that for ANY matrix $A$: $PAP^{-1}=A^{T}$

Comment: OK, I was trying to address a comment that doesn't exist anymore about the necessity of $\;n=1\;$, @GitGud ...

Comment: @DonAntonio Ohh, didn't even see it.

Comment: Ok I think I have a solution, tell me what u guys think of it: Let's assume that there is such a matrix. so $PAP^{-1} = A^{T}$, or in other words $PA=A^{T}P$. Now lets look at $PABP^{-1}=B^{T}A^{T}$, we can write it as: $A^{T}PBP^{-1}=B^{T}A^{T}$, but $PBP^{-1}=B^{T}$ so we get: $A^{T}B^{T}=B^{T}A^{T}$ which is CLEARLY not true for all matrices...What do you guys think?

Comment: How do you get to the expression after the "as:"?

Comment: switch $PA$ for $A^{T}P$, so $PABP^{-1}$ becomes $A^{T}PBP^{-1}$

Comment: It seems to work. For any two matrices $A$ and $B$, with the use of your magical $P$, we get $AB=P^{-1}A^TPP^{-1}B^TP=P^{-1}A^TB^TP=P^{-1}(BA)^TP=BA$. For $1\times 1$ matrices this is no contradiction, but for matrices of greater size multiplication is not commutative.

Comment: This argument is very nice. I will happily upvote it if you make it an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in the comments, this solution seems to work.

Assume there is such a magical $P$ so that for any matrix $A$: $PAP^{-1}=A^{T}$

we can also write it as: $PA=A^{T}P$ (simply multiply by $P$ in the right side).

now lets look at $PABP^{-1}=(AB)^{T}=B^{T}A^{T}$.

$PABP^{-1}=A^{T}PBP^{-1} = A^{T}B^{T}$

Since matrix multiplication is not commutative, $A^{T}B^{T}=B^{T}A^{T}$ does not hold for all matrices. contradiction.

Answer (score 4):

(promoted from a comment)

This solution was essentially given by the asker himself in a comment to the question.

First note that for $1\times 1$ matrices any invertible $P$ trivially works.

Then suppose such a magical $P$ also existed in general. Then for any matrices $A$ and $B$,

$$AB=P^{−1}A^TPP^{−1}B^TP=P^{−1}A^TB^TP=P^{−1}(BA)^TP=BA$$

where at first we used that $P$ works for both $A$ and $B$, and in the last equality we used that $P$ works for $BA$ too.

For 1×1 matrices this is no contradiction, but for matrices of greater size multiplication is not commutative.

Answer (score 1):

First, if you let $A=P,$ then you see that $P$ is symmetric. That means that it has an orthogonal basis of eigenvectors $e_1, \dots, e_n.$ Let $A$ be a matrix which sends $e_1$ to $e_2,$ $e_2$ to $e_3,$ etc ($e_n$ can go to $0.$) What happens to your matrices $P^{-1} A P$ and $A^t$ when applied to that basis?

**EDIT** As @julien points out, this argument works well if the ground field is the reals OR instead of transpose we use the hermitian adjoint (conjugate transpose). The argument does *not* work over $\mathbb{C}$ as stated.

Comment: It is over complex numbers. So a symmetric matrix need not be diagonalizable.

Comment: I wrote a solution I thought of in the comments. Would you be so kind as to check the validity of what I wrote? I am interested to know if the logic is valid.

Comment: Sorry to insist but for instance $A=\pmatrix{2i&1\\1&0}$ is symmetric yet not diagonalizable. Your argument works nicely if this is over real matrices, or if the OP meant the transconjugate $A^*$ when s/he wrote $A^T$.

Comment: @julien you are correct on both counts. I will add something to my answer.

Comment: @OriaGruber This answer is marked as accepted but is not quite correct. Add julien points out, his matrix $A$ is symmetric (though not "Hermitean"), but it has eigenvalues $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 = i$. So it is not diagonlizable since clearly it can't be similar to the matrix $\lambda_1 I = iI$. So this answer has a problem. I think you should mark your own answer as accepted (mine is really just a copy of yours).

Answer (score 0):

You may also prove that, if $PSP^{-1}=S$ for all *symmetric* matrices $S$, then $P$ must be a scalar multiple of the identity matrix $I$ and hence $PAP^{-1}\equiv A$ for any (symmetric or not) matrix $A$. Since $A\ne A^T$ in general, the answer to your question is negative when $n\ge2$.